# haystack autocomplete raising odd error

Tags: django, solr, autocomplete, django-haystack

Okay, so I am trying to implement autocomplete on a search field using haystack and solr in my django project but I keep running into 'reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value' error. I'm not sure how this can be becuase when I rebuild my index I see that it indexes over 200 triples in my DB.

I'm not sure I am understanding the SQS module correctly and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I want to use the Triple model fields as the autocomplete suggestions in a search from.

my model, index and view:

```
MODEL:

# Create your models here.
class Triple(models.Model):
    studies = models.ForeignKey(Studies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=550, default='')
    Predicate = models.CharField(max_length=550, default='')
    Object = models.CharField(max_length=550, default='')

    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.Subject, self.Predicate, self.Object)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.Subject, self.Predicate, self.Object)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("queries:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})


INDEX:

class TripleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    link = indexes.CharField(model_attr='studies')

    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='Object')


    def get_model(self):
        return Triple

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

the problem in my view seems to stem from this line:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the inputs to `autocomplete` that give you this error?

I think potentially passing an empty string might be triggering the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inputs to autocomplete.  Are you talking about the index EdgeNgramField?

Comment: I just meant the value of complete_auto that you pass into SearchQuerySet().autocomplete()

Comment: Oh I think I see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm passing it the search_query not the term query set I want to use for the autocomplete.  Now I am trying these two lines.                                                                autocontent = Triple.objects.all()                                                             sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto='autocontent')